# Django: is it possible to set DateInput widget limits for maximum and minimum dates?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

my Date widget in **forms.py** looks like this:

```
class DateInput(DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'


class TaskCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TaskModel
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('task_project',)
        widgets = {
            'task_baseline_start': DateInput(),
            'task_baseline_finish': DateInput(),
            'task_scheduled_start': DateInput(),
            'task_scheduled_finish': DateInput(),
            'task_real_start': DateInput(),
            'task_real_finish': DateInput(),
        }
```

The problem is whenever someone introduces a date too far into the future/past, some other parts of the application get all messed up (like graphs and other stuff).

I've tried the following:

```
class DateInput(DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
    attrs = {'min': '2020-01-01'}
```

But the widget keeps accepting dates before 2020-01-01.

Edit: If I set the attribute on every "DateInput()" instance, the widget will respect the limit, i.e.:

```
class TaskCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TaskModel
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ('task_project',)
        widgets = {
            'task_baseline_start': DateInput(attrs={'min':'2019-01-01'}),
            'task_baseline_finish': DateInput(attrs={'min':'2019-01-01'}),
            'task_scheduled_start': DateInput(attrs={'min':'2019-01-01'}),
            'task_scheduled_finish': DateInput(attrs={'min':'2019-01-01'}),
            'task_real_start': DateInput(attrs={'min':'2019-01-01'}),
            'task_real_finish': DateInput(attrs={'min':'2019-01-01'}),
        }
```

Now this code hurts my feelings and I feel completely disrespectful for the DRY standards. Is there any better way to set this constraint just once?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The widget does not look at the `attrs` class attribute. You can add it to the clone, so:

```
class DateInput(DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.attrs.setdefault('min', '2020-01-01')
```

By using [**`.setdefault(…)`** <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault), it will not override a different value if you specify one when you construct a `DateInput` object.

Note that a widget is *not* validated by Django. You thus still should add a validator in the model (or form field) to prevent against for example forged requests.